# Spark 3.4.1 New spark standalone cluster issue: check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Spark version: spark-3.4.1-bin-hadoop3

I am setting up a standalone cluster and I am seeing the error

```
~ ./test-submit.py 
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
23/07/04 00:53:15 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
23/07/04 00:53:34 WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
^CERROR
```

my code is

```
#!/bin/env python3 
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.types import *

spark = SparkSession.builder \
  .master("spark://10.4.42.58:7077").appName("examplejob").getOrCreate()
  # .master("local[2]").appName("examplejob").getOrCreate()

spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("DEBUG")

HOUSING_DATA = 'example/cal_housing.data'
schema = StructType([
    StructField("long", FloatType(), nullable=True),
    StructField("lat", FloatType(), nullable=True),
    StructField("medage", FloatType(), nullable=True),
    StructField("totrooms", FloatType(), nullable=True),
    StructField("totbdrms", FloatType(), nullable=True),
    StructField("pop", FloatType(), nullable=True),
    StructField("houshlds", FloatType(), nullable=True),
    StructField("medinc", FloatType(), nullable=True),
    StructField("medhv", FloatType(), nullable=True)]
)
housing_df = spark.read.csv(path=HOUSING_DATA, schema=schema)
print(housing_df.take(5))
```

dataset is from https://github.com/mikeizbicki/datasets/blob/master/csv/statlib/cal_housing.data

The Spark Master is showing:

```
Alive Workers: 2
Cores in use: 8 Total, 0 Used
Memory in use: 62.0 GiB Total, 0.0 B Used
Resources in use:
Applications: 0 Running, 10 Completed
Drivers: 0 Running, 0 Completed
Status: ALIVE
```

when I run with spark-submit I see the same error. eg:

```
$ /opt/spark-3.4.1-bin-hadoop3/bin/spark-submit --master spark://10.42.4.58:7077 ~/test-submit.py

23/07/04 01:06:17 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 1 missing tasks from ResultStage 0 (MapPartitionsRDD[2] at take at /home/user/test-submit.py:24) (first 15 tasks are for partitions Vector(0))
23/07/04 01:06:17 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 0.0 with 1 tasks resource profile 0
23/07/04 01:06:32 WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
```

I can run simple py spark scripts, but the above is showing a resource error

Another attempt with just head() and addFile same issue

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark import SparkFiles
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext

spark = SparkSession.builder \
  .master("spark://10.42.4.58:7077").appName("examplejob").getOrCreate()
  # .master("local[2]").appName("examplejob").getOrCreate()
# spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("DEBUG")

spark.sparkContext.addFile("file:///home/user/example/cal_housing.data")
schema = StructType([
    StructField("long", FloatType(), nullable=True),
    StructField("lat", FloatType(), nullable=True),
    StructField("medage", FloatType(), nullable=True),
    StructField("totrooms", FloatType(), nullable=True),
    StructField("totbdrms", FloatType(), nullable=True),
    StructField("pop", FloatType(), nullable=True),
    StructField("houshlds", FloatType(), nullable=True),
    StructField("medinc", FloatType(), nullable=True),
    StructField("medhv", FloatType(), nullable=True)]
)

housing_df = spark.read.option("delimiter", ";") \
  .option("inferSchema", "true") \
  .csv(SparkFiles.get("cal_housing.data"), header=True)

print(housing_df.head())
```

Answer (score 0):

it ended up being a DNS issue, `--conf spark.driver.host=$(hostname -i)` fixes the issue when using spark-submit